# 2.2.2.2 uses an invalid security certificate

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, wildcard, domain-masking

I have bought a wild-card certificate for *.helloworld.com in "Godaddy" and had tried to use it in "2.2.2.2" that is in digital ocean which has my apache installed, ssl configured based on the above certificate.

On trying to run the "https://2.2.2.2", i received the following error:

"2.2.2.2" uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for the following names:
 *.helloworld.com, helloworld.com

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

To overcome this issue, i had tried to do a forward with masking in "godaddy" for "x.helloworld.com" which is pointing to "https://2.2.2.2".

Still, i am facing the Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain.

I am interested in having a clear understanding of my issue. Kindly Someone help me by providing your views on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the ip address with hostname to your host file, so you can use the hostname to connect to the server. If you want to use the ip address, you need a certificat for that ip address....

Comment: can you please provide an use case scenario with which i can understand better ? Also, Can you guide me to a vendor who provide ssl certificate for ip ?